# How to extract text from a web element using Selenium and C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to fetch the title (9,804,541) from this piece of Html Code.

```
<p class="ring_SecondaryValue" style="color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
 font-size: 16px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;
 text-overflow: ellipsis; vertical-align: middle; white-space:
 nowrap;"><div class="ring_secondaryMeasureSum"
 title="9,804,541">9,805K</div></p>
```

I had tried this piece of code:

```
string left_value =driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ring_secondaryMeasureSum")).GetAttribute("title");
```

Comment: Might be possible ring_secondaryMeasureSum is used many times, so locate element using xpath

Comment: Yeah, but getting same XPath in chrome developer option

Comment: Also I can't add second condtition (@title='9,804,541) bcoz, its dynamic

Comment: I updated the asnwer

Comment: Still It is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

In java it is like this

```
  WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ring_secondaryMeasureSum')][contains(text(),'')]"));
            System.out.println(title.getAttribute("title"));
```

I tried in c Sharp also, you may check syntax error as I am not good in c sharp

```
IWebElement title = driver.FindElement((By.Xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ring_secondaryMeasureSum')][contains(text(),'')]"));

string titleText= title.GetAttribute("title");
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to extract the title **9,804,541** you can use either of the following solution:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  string left_value = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("p.ring_SecondaryValue > div.ring_secondaryMeasureSum")).GetAttribute("title");
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  string left_value = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='ring_SecondaryValue']/div[@class='ring_secondaryMeasureSum']")).GetAttribute("title");
  ```